# My JSON loads in Safari but not in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-chrome, safari

I have a json with data. You can check it online on http://misterwolfs.be/keyboard/.

My json loads normally in safari but in chrome it won't get my data!

Dus anyone knows if there is something wrong with my json or if chrome is harder to get than safari?

This is how I try to get my json data :

```
$.get('resources/json/data.json', 
        function(json)
        {   

            console.log('json', json);
        keyboardController.keys = json.keyboard;


        }, 
        'json'
    ).success(function () { console.log('test success'); });
```

And this is my json file

```
{
"keyboard" : {  
    "esc": [{"Monday":80,"Tuesday":35,"Wednesday":63,"Thursday":51,"Friday":129,"Saturday":55,"Sunday":108,"Total":521}],
    "f1": [{"Monday":6,"Tuesday":9,"Wednesday":18,"Thursday":4,"Friday":3,"Saturday":7,"Sunday":6,"Total":53}],
    "f2": [{"Monday":9,"Tuesday":3,"Wednesday":5,"Thursday":18,"Friday":6,"Saturday":19,"Sunday":7,"Total":67}],
    "f3": [{"Monday":2,"Tuesday":10,"Wednesday":9,"Thursday":3,"Friday":1,"Saturday":3,"Sunday":4,"Total":32}],
    "f4": [{"Monday":9,"Tuesday":5,"Wednesday":3,"Thursday":7,"Friday":15,"Saturday":5,"Sunday":8,"Total":52}],
    "f5": [{"Monday":3,"Tuesday":9,"Wednesday":6,"Thursday":4,"Friday":9,"Saturday":1,"Sunday":4,"Total":36}],
    "f6": [{"Monday":5,"Tuesday":19,"Wednesday":9,"Thursday":3,"Friday":7,"Saturday":8,"Sunday":3,"Total":54}],
    "f7": [{"Monday":8,"Tuesday":3,"Wednesday":4,"Thursday":9,"Friday":18,"Saturday":12,"Sunday":3,"Total":57}],
    "f8": [{"Monday":3,"Tuesday":5,"Wednesday":7,"Thursday":14,"Friday":3,"Saturday":4,"Sunday":2,"Total":38}],
    "f9": [{"Monday":8,"Tuesday":7,"Wednesday":14,"Thursday":4,"Friday":9,"Saturday":9,"Sunday":1,"Total":52}],
    "f10": [{"Monday":3,"Tuesday":9,"Wednesday":4,"Thursday":6,"Friday":3,"Saturday":5,"Sunday":2,"Total":32}],
    "f12": [{"Monday":6,"Tuesday":2,"Wednesday":2,"Thursday":9,"Friday":4,"Saturday":7,"Sunday":16,"Total":46}],
    "f13": [{"Monday":9,"Tuesday":12,"Wednesday":6,"Thursday":17,"Friday":8,"Saturday":14,"Sunday":15,"Total":81}],
    "#": [{"Monday":6,"Tuesday":10,"Wednesday":6,"Thursday":2,"Friday":12,"Saturday":7,"Sunday":30,"Total":73}],
    "1": [{"Monday":204,"Tuesday":60,"Wednesday":89,"Thursday":52,"Friday":138,"Saturday":99,"Sunday":137,"Total":779}],
    "2": [{"Monday":59,"Tuesday":22,"Wednesday":32,"Thursday":29,"Friday":89,"Saturday":92,"Sunday":97,"Total":419}],
    "3": [{"Monday":44,"Tuesday":78,"Wednesday":60,"Thursday":35,"Friday":108,"Saturday":68,"Sunday":101,"Total":494}],
    "4": [{"Monday":145,"Tuesday":156,"Wednesday":139,"Thursday":72,"Friday":40,"Saturday":58,"Sunday":117,"Total":727}],
    "5": [{"Monday":248,"Tuesday":191,"Wednesday":188,"Thursday":90,"Friday":112,"Saturday":109,"Sunday":122,"Total":1060}],
    "6": [{"Monday":28,"Tuesday":13,"Wednesday":31,"Thursday":15,"Friday":84,"Saturday":15,"Sunday":28,"Total":214}],
    "7": [{"Monday":26,"Tuesday":29,"Wednesday":23,"Thursday":12,"Friday":59,"Saturday":17,"Sunday":22,"Total":188}],
    "8": [{"Monday":31,"Tuesday":15,"Wednesday":26,"Thursday":28,"Friday":43,"Saturday":46,"Sunday":54,"Total":243}],
    "9": [{"Monday":37,"Tuesday":23,"Wednesday":14,"Thursday":15,"Friday":30,"Saturday":50,"Sunday":138,"Total":165}],
    "0": [{"Monday":94,"Tuesday":101,"Wednesday":99,"Thursday":87,"Friday":59,"Saturday":112,"Sunday":76,"Total":690}],
    "°": [{"Monday":124,"Tuesday":105,"Wednesday":91,"Thursday":53,"Friday":32,"Saturday":40,"Sunday":88,"Total":521}],
    "_": [{"Monday":105,"Tuesday":53,"Wednesday":60,"Thursday":91,"Friday":85,"Saturday":53,"Sunday":39,"Total":535}],
    "del": [{"Monday":1474,"Tuesday":1639,"Wednesday":1311,"Thursday":875,"Friday":1911,"Saturday":997,"Sunday":1536,"Total":9743}],
    "tab": [{"Monday":1189,"Tuesday":1773,"Wednesday":1379,"Thursday":834,"Friday":1632,"Saturday":989,"Sunday":1511,"Total":9307}],
    "A": [{"Monday":880,"Tuesday":754,"Wednesday":520,"Thursday":290,"Friday":432,"Saturday":420,"Sunday":892,"Total":4188}],
    "Z": [{"Monday":230,"Tuesday":271,"Wednesday":234,"Thursday":428,"Friday":829,"Saturday":204,"Sunday":236,"Total":2432}],
    "E": [{"Monday":1370,"Tuesday":919,"Wednesday":670,"Thursday":411,"Friday":219,"Saturday":651,"Sunday":1144,"Total":5384}],
    "R": [{"Monday":674,"Tuesday":790,"Wednesday":646,"Thursday":563,"Friday":438,"Saturday":687,"Sunday":1056,"Total":4854}],
    "T": [{"Monday":728,"Tuesday":459,"Wednesday":323,"Thursday":206,"Friday":684,"Saturday":188,"Sunday":602,"Total":3190}],
    "Y": [{"Monday":76,"Tuesday":201,"Wednesday":159,"Thursday":44,"Friday":58,"Saturday":48,"Sunday":142,"Total":728}],
    "U": [{"Monday":236,"Tuesday":171,"Wednesday":114,"Thursday":76,"Friday":430,"Saturday":70,"Sunday":220,"Total":1317}],
    "I": [{"Monday":561,"Tuesday":396,"Wednesday":257,"Thursday":196,"Friday":819,"Saturday":271,"Sunday":499,"Total":2999}],
    "O": [{"Monday":763,"Tuesday":443,"Wednesday":353,"Thursday":221,"Friday":439,"Saturday":313,"Sunday":479,"Total":3011}],
    "P": [{"Monday":305,"Tuesday":179,"Wednesday":122,"Thursday":106,"Friday":289,"Saturday":175,"Sunday":211,"Total":1387}],
    "¨": [{"Monday":19,"Tuesday":8,"Wednesday":8,"Thursday":17,"Friday":34,"Saturday":3,"Sunday":7,"Total":96}],
    "*": [{"Monday":20,"Tuesday":70,"Wednesday":30,"Thursday":17,"Friday":49,"Saturday":4,"Sunday":22,"Total":182}],
    "caps": [{"Monday":49,"Tuesday":1,"Wednesday":39,"Thursday":2,"Friday":20,"Saturday":29,"Sunday":12,"Total":74}],
    "Q": [{"Monday":55,"Tuesday":28,"Wednesday":654,"Thursday":24,"Friday":239,"Saturday":16,"Sunday":48,"Total":1064}],
    "S": [{"Monday":717,"Tuesday":827,"Wednesday":411,"Thursday":487,"Friday":1012,"Saturday":506,"Sunday":864,"Total":4824}],
    "D": [{"Monday":477,"Tuesday":499,"Wednesday":100,"Thursday":363,"Friday":232,"Saturday":260,"Sunday":507,"Total":2438}],
    "F": [{"Monday":150,"Tuesday":150,"Wednesday":165,"Thursday":66,"Friday":101,"Saturday":54,"Sunday":212,"Total":898}],
    "G": [{"Monday":270,"Tuesday":152,"Wednesday":115,"Thursday":89,"Friday":310,"Saturday":142,"Sunday":189,"Total":1267}],
    "H": [{"Monday":359,"Tuesday":176,"Wednesday":50,"Thursday":105,"Friday":213,"Saturday":112,"Sunday":188,"Total":1203}],
    "J": [{"Monday":131,"Tuesday":133,"Wednesday":195,"Thursday":48,"Friday":80,"Saturday":59,"Sunday":95,"Total":741}],
    "K": [{"Monday":217,"Tuesday":215,"Wednesday":218,"Thursday":84,"Friday":128,"Saturday":137,"Sunday":201,"Total":1200}],
    "L": [{"Monday":382,"Tuesday":261,"Wednesday":118,"Thursday":114,"Friday":248,"Saturday":140,"Sunday":341,"Total":1604}],
    "M": [{"Monday":312,"Tuesday":158,"Wednesday":13,"Thursday":96,"Friday":213,"Saturday":151,"Sunday":249,"Total":1192}],
    "%": [{"Monday":6,"Tuesday":10,"Wednesday":27,"Thursday":3,"Friday":23,"Saturday":1,"Sunday":13,"Total":83}],
    "£": [{"Monday":5,"Tuesday":1,"Wednesday":12,"Thursday":3,"Friday":8,"Saturday":1,"Sunday":4,"Total":22}],
    "enter": [{"Monday":1200,"Tuesday":878,"Wednesday":988,"Thursday":419,"Friday":1532,"Saturday":480,"Sunday":1015,"Total":6512}],
    ">": [{"Monday":62,"Tuesday":210,"Wednesday":185,"Thursday":114,"Friday":109,"Saturday":143,"Sunday":50,"Total":873}],
    "W": [{"Monday":324,"Tuesday":75,"Wednesday":68,"Thursday":73,"Friday":265,"Saturday":66,"Sunday":370,"Total":1241}],
    "X": [{"Monday":109,"Tuesday":264,"Wednesday":292,"Thursday":142,"Friday":89,"Saturday":134,"Sunday":137,"Total":1167}],
    "C": [{"Monday":342,"Tuesday":367,"Wednesday":343,"Thursday":137,"Friday":263,"Saturday":195,"Sunday":286,"Total":1933}],
    "V": [{"Monday":295,"Tuesday":121,"Wednesday":86,"Thursday":52,"Friday":238,"Saturday":71,"Sunday":275,"Total":1138}],
    "B": [{"Monday":225,"Tuesday":454,"Wednesday":284,"Thursday":211,"Friday":382,"Saturday":376,"Sunday":191,"Total":2123}],
    "N": [{"Monday":690,"Tuesday":102,"Wednesday":79,"Thursday":27,"Friday":373,"Saturday":90,"Sunday":524,"Total":1885}],
    "?": [{"Monday":146,"Tuesday":268,"Wednesday":222,"Thursday":131,"Friday":200,"Saturday":27,"Sunday":49,"Total":1043}],
    ".": [{"Monday":264,"Tuesday":164,"Wednesday":145,"Thursday":83,"Friday":219,"Saturday":115,"Sunday":220,"Total":1210}],
    "/": [{"Monday":173,"Tuesday":47,"Wednesday":79,"Thursday":79,"Friday":120,"Saturday":22,"Sunday":182,"Total":692}],
    "+": [{"Monday":90,"Tuesday":64,"Wednesday":51,"Thursday":53,"Friday":43,"Saturday":29,"Sunday":36,"Total":366}],
    "shift": [{"Monday":1197,"Tuesday":741,"Wednesday":760,"Thursday":421,"Friday":998,"Saturday":630,"Sunday":939,"Total":5686}],
    "fn": [{"Monday":89,"Tuesday":60,"Wednesday":49,"Thursday":86,"Friday":100,"Saturday":32,"Sunday":84,"Total":500}],
    "ctrl": [{"Monday":37,"Tuesday":10,"Wednesday":7,"Thursday":24,"Friday":30,"Saturday":27,"Sunday":70,"Total":205}],
    "space": [{"Monday":1556,"Tuesday":3988,"Wednesday":692,"Thursday":541,"Friday":1932,"Saturday":970,"Sunday":1112,"Total":10791}],
    "cmd": [{"Monday":1122,"Tuesday":1724,"Wednesday":1254,"Thursday":826,"Friday":1349,"Saturday":767,"Sunday":1478,"Total":8523}],
    "alt": [{"Monday":96,"Tuesday":150,"Wednesday":97,"Thursday":28,"Friday":128,"Saturday":39,"Sunday":55,"Total":593}],
    "left": [{"Monday":332,"Tuesday":1026,"Wednesday":307,"Thursday":229,"Friday":754,"Saturday":227,"Sunday":480,"Total":3355}],
    "down": [{"Monday":394,"Tuesday":1438,"Wednesday":442,"Thursday":314,"Friday":912,"Saturday":226,"Sunday":432,"Total":4258}],
    "right": [{"Monday":326,"Tuesday":1580,"Wednesday":436,"Thursday":194,"Friday":832,"Saturday":298,"Sunday":454,"Total":4120}],
    "up": [{"Monday":207,"Tuesday":734,"Wednesday":205,"Thursday":114,"Friday":349,"Saturday":130,"Sunday":165,"Total":1904}]   
}
}
```

Comment: Possibly your server isn't delivering the file with `application/json` HTTP headers. Try using [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) instead of `$.get()`.

Comment: Are you sure it's working in safari?  you have a console error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` meaning you are trying to access values in your object incorrectly `b=keyboardController.keys[keyboardController.key][0]`

Comment: I am willing to bet this is the classic case of making an asynchronous call and acting like it is a synchronous call.

Comment: @Blazemonger no even $.getJSON() won't work...

yes in safari it is working on my laptop. I get the error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined in chrome but not in safari!

Comment: @epascarello any idea how to fix it?

Comment: in Chrome - this is what exists for your keyboardController object `Object {keys: "", key: "", i: 1, count: 1, move_keys: Array[4]…}`

Comment: @RobbertWolfsDo not call the next step until the JSON has been loaded. That is how you would fix it.

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ does it work in chrome for you?

Comment: @epascarello how do I know when my json is loaded?

Comment: There is the callback, learn about the code you use! AKA, you trigger the next step where you have the console line in your code.